# iOS - Using dealloc to remove observer

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, dealloc, observers

I have a basic question regarding removing observer.

I have a ViewController parent class which is inherited by 3 ViewController child classes.
eg. BookVC -> BookHotelVC, BookFlightVC, BookTrainVC

Here, I added an observer in the `viewDidLoad` of parent class (I do `[super viewDidLoad]` in child ViewControllers)  which notifies a method written in parent class. My code-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(BookingCompleted:) name:@"BookingCompleted" object:nil];
```

Now I want to remove the observer when I move away from any of the child ViewControllers, but I can't write `[super dealloc]` in `dealloc` of each child ViewController because ARC doesn't permit this.

How can I remove the observer which is set ? Because whenever I move to child ViewController, a new observer is added which causes weird things (like, calling that method twice/thrice... - invoking alert twice/thrice...).

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the observers in `dealloc` is fine, do not call `[super dealloc]` (as you saw, with ARC enabled, the compiler won't let you), simply write:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeYourObservers];
}
```

Comment: with ARC you even can not explicitly call dealloc :)

Comment: the word need doesn't fit in my opinion, you simply can not use it

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call `super`!  In ARC it's not required (see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#dealloc).

```
-(void)dealloc {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```

Comment: You mean I should write `dealloc` in parent class itself ?
If its that, I had done it in the first place, but its not getting called.

Comment: @pRimei5 Are you sure all references to that object have been freed?